# Where does chrome store unpacked extensions local storage files

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Chrome which uses the local storage API.  I would like to manually modify some of the data that has been stored by my extension  in order to do some testing.  I've determined that my installed (packaged) extensions use sqlite 3 files located here:
`C:\Users\golear\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`
but I can't find similar files for my unpacked extension.  I've used the extension key to search my entire drive as I see that the packaged app use their keys in the names of their local storage sqlite files.  I did find 3 folder names using my extension's key but none of them appear to have the file I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Mac, it's in `Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Extension Settings/<extension id>`. I'm guessing it should be in similar folder for Windows.

This is also a good extension for viewing what you're looking for: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb

Comment: I found a file in that folder which appears to contain the data i'm looking for but I can't figure out what file format it is.  When I try to open with a SQLite browser it tells me it's the wrong format. When I open with a text editor I can see the contents (what I have stored) but it displays characters that make it look like binary data: `Ä ±ÌA           `

Comment: @GabeO'Leary have you tried using the chrome extension?

Comment: Yeah I did. Took me a little bit to figure it out, but I've got it now. Thanks!